# R: one line code for correlation tests

Tags: r

I have two different data frames. From one I calculated `Richness` and in the other one I have `Environmental Variables` that I wish to correlate with each other as it follows in my code:

```
cor.test(Richness, E.4$Temp...C.)
cor.test(Richness, E.4$Cond..µS.cm.1.)
cor.test(Richness, E.4$pH)
cor.test(Richness, E.4$Alkalinity.Gran..mequiv.m.3.)
cor.test(Richness, E.4$HCO3)
cor.test(Richness, E.4$NO3.N..mg.m.3.)
cor.test(Richness, E.4$SO4..mg.l.)
```

This is just a short example. The E.4 data frame has 30 columns. Could you maybe please help me with an idea of how to write a one-line code for all this?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure... try `lapply( E.4 , cor.test , y = Richness )`. Your x and y have swapped round in this example.

Comment: One more thing, Is there a way to extract the p-values from all these correlation tests and add them to a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Richness = 1:100)
df2 <- data.frame(Var1 = df1$Richness + rnorm(100), Var2 = rnorm(100))


lapply(1:ncol(df2), function(x) cor.test(df1$Richness, df2[ ,x]))
```

Update:

For the p-values you could use:

```
sapply(1:ncol(df2), function(x) cor.test(df1$Richness, df2[ ,x])$p.value)
```

Comment: Or you can just do `lapply( df2 , cor.test , x = df1[,1] )` so then it becomes the same as the comment I left.